# Editing as wwwrun

Tags: web-server, permissions

Let's say you have a web server where the htdocs and everything in it is owned by the apache daemon, wwwrun and it's group, www.  What's the best way to set up an external web editor such as Bluefish or Coda that logs in via ssh(sftp), and edit files while still keeping permissions intact?

The best I've been able to figure out is logging into the box itself as myself and using sudo:

```
sudo -u wwwrun vi index.php
```

Obviously, I can't do that with Coda.  Maybe I'm going about it the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Access Control Lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list)

Not quite as common in the *nix land but very useful. Takes away a lot of the "smart group management" problems and allows to define default. [getfacl](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=getfacl&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian+5.0+lenny&format=html&locale=en) and [setfacl](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=setfacl&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian+5.0+lenny&format=html&locale=en) are your friends. However take notive that with ext* you need to mount the the `acl` option.

To get access with any editor use sshfs (fuse filesystem) on the client side, it may be a bit sluggish depending on your connection but you will mostly deal with normal filesystem semantics.

Answer (score 0):

If `www` group has write permissions add the user you're logging as to this group.

Comment: And either setgid www the directory or make www the users primary group